# Bar High Chart with different positive and negative scale interval values

Tags: highcharts, angular8, angular-highcharts

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  credits: {
            enabled: false,
            
        },
        legend: {
           
            enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
            type: "bar",
            height: 180,
            reflow: false,
            alignTicks: false,
          
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        accessibility: {
            point: {
                valueDescriptionFormat: "{index}. Agency {xDescription}, {y}%.",
            },
        },
        xAxis: {
            visible: false,
        },
        yAxis: [
            
            {
               
               
                
                tickPositioner: function() {
                  
                  let step = 50,
                  step2 =250,
               
                    ret = [],
                    ret2 = [],
                    arr=[]
              
                  for (var i = this.min; i <= 0; i+= step) {
                      ret.push(i);
                  }
                  for (var i = 0; i <= this.max; i+= step2) {
                      ret2.push(i);
                  }
             
                 
                   arr= ret.concat(ret2)
                    return arr;
                },
                title: {
                    text: null,
                },
                linkedTo: 0,
                labels: {
                   
                    enabled:true,
                    step: 1
                 
                },
                accessibility: {
                    description: "Percentage population",
                    rangeDescription: "Range: 0 to 5%",
                },
            },
        ],

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: "normal",
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    inside: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                        
                          return (this.y > 1000) ? Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / 1000, 3) + "K": this.y;
                        
                      },
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
                },
            },
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return (
                    // "<b>" +
                    // this.point.series.data.map(x=>x.y) +
                   
                    // "</b><br/>" +
                    "Segment: " +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 1) +
                    ""
                );
            },
        },
        series: [
           
            {
                type: "bar",
                // name: (segment[0] && segment[4])?"Top Agencies":"Bottom Agencies",
                borderRadius: 12,
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0.05,
                color: {//set le5end point color
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, "#46a4eb"],
                        [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                    ],
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        y: 2000,
                        title:"HIII",
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#46a4eb"],
                                [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            // text: "BTS",
                            // score: "27,000",
                            text:"Abc",
                            score:2000,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: 1000,
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#46a4eb"],
                                [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:"Abc",
                            score:1000
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: 1300,
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#46a4eb"],
                                [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:"CVB",
                            score:1300
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y:1400,
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#46a4eb"],
                                [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:"Abc",
                            score:1400
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y:760,
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#46a4eb"],
                                [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:"Abc",
                            score:760
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: 900,
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#f48686"],
                                [1, "#f05e5e"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:"Jhd",
                            // score:"6000",
                            score:900
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y:-50,
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#f48686"],
                                [1, "#f05e5e"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:"Uit",
                            score:-50
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: -40,
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#f48686"],
                                [1, "#f05e5e"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:"TPS",
                            score:-40
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: -15,
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#f48686"],
                                [1, "#f05e5e"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:"Pop",
                            score:-15
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: -10,
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#f48686"],
                                [1, "#f05e5e"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:"BVC",
                            score:-10
                        },
                    },
                ],
                dataLabels: [
                    {
                        align: "left",
                        format: "({point.custom.score})",
                        enabled: true,
                        padding: 15,
                        color: "#FFFFFF",

                        style: {
                            fontSize: "10px",
                            textShadow: false,
                            textOutline: "0",
                            fontWeight: "light",
                            fontFamily: 'Muli',
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        align: "right",
                        format: "{point.custom.text}",
                        padding: 15,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: "10px",
                            textShadow: false,
                            textOutline: "0",
                            fontWeight: "light",
                            fontFamily: 'Muli',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 310px; 
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
  height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <p class="highcharts-description">
    Bar chart showing horizontal columns. This chart type is often
    beneficial for smaller screens, as the user can scroll through the data
    vertically, and axis labels are easy to read.
  </p>
</figure>
```

My requirement is I want to make a Bar chart with different interval ranges of positive and negative y-axis. Like for positive y-axis my interval range is around 250+ and for negative y-axis my range is around 15-20 or it sets ranges  according to the given data dynamically.

Another issue is I have somehow manage to solve the above given issue but my origin is displacing from center so in short I want to keep my origin at the center with different ranges of positive and negative y-axis.

Is there any possibility to limit the width of +y-axis and -y-axis to center the origin ?

Here's code pen link [barchart](https://codepen.io/ezzahwaseem/pen/abmRoNP)

**This is my graph**

[image]

**This is what I want even if positive value is too high or negative value is too low.**

[image]

**Code is here**

```
export const getAgencyChartOption = (data) =>{
    let name=data.map(x=>x.agenciesName)
    let segment=data.map(x=>x.segments)
    
    let obj: Highcharts.Options = {
        credits: {
            enabled: false,
            
        },
        legend: {
           
            enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
            type: "bar",
            height: 180,
            reflow: false,
            alignTicks: false,
          
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        accessibility: {
            point: {
                valueDescriptionFormat: "{index}. Agency {xDescription}, {y}%.",
            },
        },
        xAxis: {
            visible: false,
        },
        yAxis: [
            
            {
               
               
                
                tickPositioner: function() {
                  
                  let step = 50,
                  step2 =250,
               
                    ret = [],
                    ret2 = [],
                    arr=[]
              
                  for (var i = this.min; i <= 0; i+= step) {
                      ret.push(i);
                  }
                  for (var i = 0; i <= this.max; i+= step2) {
                      ret2.push(i);
                  }
             
                 
                   arr= ret.concat(ret2)
                    return arr;
                },
                title: {
                    text: null,
                },
                linkedTo: 0,
                labels: {
                   
                    enabled:true,
                    step: 1
                 
                },
                accessibility: {
                    description: "Percentage population",
                    rangeDescription: "Range: 0 to 5%",
                },
            },
        ],

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: "normal",
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    inside: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                        
                          return (this.y > 1000) ? Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / 1000, 3) + "K": this.y;
                        
                      },
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
                },
            },
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return (
                    // "<b>" +
                    // this.point.series.data.map(x=>x.y) +
                   
                    // "</b><br/>" +
                    "Segment: " +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 1) +
                    ""
                );
            },
        },
        series: [
           
            {
                type: "bar",
                // name: (segment[0] && segment[4])?"Top Agencies":"Bottom Agencies",
                borderRadius: 12,
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0.05,
                color: {//set le5end point color
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, "#46a4eb"],
                        [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                    ],
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        y: Number(segment[0]),
                        title:"HIII",
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#46a4eb"],
                                [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            // text: "BTS",
                            // score: "27,000",
                            text:name[0],
                            score:segment[0]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: Number(segment[1]),
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#46a4eb"],
                                [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:name[1],
                            score:segment[1]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: Number(segment[2]),
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#46a4eb"],
                                [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:name[2],
                            score:segment[2]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: Number(segment[ 3]),
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#46a4eb"],
                                [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:name[3],
                            score:segment[3]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: Number(segment[4]),
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#46a4eb"],
                                [1, "#6cbdfb"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:name[4],
                            score:segment[4]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: Number(segment[5]),
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#f48686"],
                                [1, "#f05e5e"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:name[5],
                            // score:"6000",
                            score:segment[5]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: Number(segment[6]),
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#f48686"],
                                [1, "#f05e5e"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:name[6],
                            score:segment[6]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: Number(segment[7]),
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#f48686"],
                                [1, "#f05e5e"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:name[7],
                            score:segment[7]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: Number(segment[8]),
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#f48686"],
                                [1, "#f05e5e"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:name[8],
                            score:segment[8]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: Number(segment[9]),
                        color: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, "#f48686"],
                                [1, "#f05e5e"],
                            ],
                        },
                        custom: {
                            text:name[9],
                            score:segment[9]
                        },
                    },
                ],
                dataLabels: [
                    {
                        align: "left",
                        format: "({point.custom.score})",
                        enabled: true,
                        padding: 15,
                        color: "#FFFFFF",

                        style: {
                            fontSize: "10px",
                            textShadow: false,
                            textOutline: "0",
                            fontWeight: "light",
                            fontFamily: 'Muli',
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        align: "right",
                        format: "{point.custom.text}",
                        padding: 15,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: "10px",
                            textShadow: false,
                            textOutline: "0",
                            fontWeight: "light",
                            fontFamily: 'Muli',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
   

    return obj
}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with the sample of the data on some online editor that I could work on? You can start from this template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0cyrbo2m/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel  Code Pen Link is here .. [https://codepen.io/ezzahwaseem/pen/abmRoNP](https://codepen.io/ezzahwaseem/pen/abmRoNP)

Comment: @SebastianWędzel could you help us, I arrived here wanting to find out the same thing.

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like is done in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rcabd63n/?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Yes adding 1 thing, I need to minimize -y-axis interval like If I am having negative values -10,-20,-30 which is quite smaller than +y-axis values so my negative y-axis interval should  be of 20 or 30 or some small value not 500, hope you got me!

Comment: @EzzahWaseem in this case you should consider dividing your data into two separate series and attach the negative values to the second yAxis, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lo2r0tkc/

Comment: @SebastianWędze Thanks man! I have sorted this .